# Redirection with HTACCESS including GET parameters

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a specific .htaccess defined as is, in order to reroute all traffic from root folder to identical URL in a subfolder with exceptions on sub-domains.

Here's my file:

```
#RewriteEngine on 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.fr/blog/$1 [R=301,QSA]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^joe\.mydomain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^lab\.mydomain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^joe(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^lab(.*)
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.mydomain.fr/blog/

</IfModule>
```

This file does exactly what I want: when I input something like `www.mydomain.fr/wp-admin` for example, it will redirect to `www.mydomain.fr/blog/wp-admin`, but will exclude subdomains `joe.mydomain.fr` and `lab.mydomain.fr` from redirection.

However, what happens is that if I go to `joe.mydomain.fr?test=1`, the server will simply redirect  me to `joe.mydomain.fr` but the GET parameter disappears.

How can I avoid that?

I tried replacing `[NC]` with `[QSA]` or `[R=301,QSA]`, but I get an Internal Server Error.

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to combine RewriteCond and RedirectMatch this way makes no sense to begin with - RewriteConds affect RewriteRules, they have no influence whatsoever on any of the Redirect* directives.

Answer (score 0):

After spending my day documenting about how .htaccess files actually work, I was finally able to solve my problem with the following file, inspired by the one from Abhishek Gurjar:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /s

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^joe\.mydomain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^lab\.mydomain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.mydomain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/joe
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/lab
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.fr/blog/$1 [R=301]

</IfModule>
```

FYI, the 3 first lines are mandatory with my provider 1&1 apparently...

What I changed is the REQUEST_URI from being **!^joe(.* )** and **!^lab(.*)** to **!/joe** and **!/lab** and then excluding the blog.mydomain.fr URL as well to avoid problems with blog.mydomain.fr/joe or blog.mydomain.fr/lab if ever one day I use them.

Finally, I had to redirect my sub-domains in my 1&1 client interface to the subfolders of my webspace instead of the URL in hard, meaning:

- Instead of redirecting joe.mydomain.fr to http://www.mydomain.fr/joe, I redirect it to /www/joe/

That configuration now allows me to type in an URL such as joe.mydomain.fr?dnt=1 while getting redirected to http://www.mydomain.fr/joe?dnt=1 which is exactly what I wanted to do.

I hope this helps others.
Thanks for the help.